# How to get the distribution of a random variable from the distribution of their summation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Let ${\textstyle \{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}}\}$ be a sequence of independent and identical random variables. The distribution of $X_n$ is unknown.

Assuming that we know the distribution of the following summation:
$${S}\equiv \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{X_n}{n^2}$$

Would it be possible to find the distribution of $X_n$ from $S$ ?

Comment: In case $X$ and $Y$ are independent with distribution densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, their has a density distribution of $f_X* f_Y$. So in your case you'll have a lot of convolutions, and the question is whether it's possible from the result of convolution to deduce its source. Sounds like a tough procedure.

Comment: In the original problem, all $X_n$ are independent and identical. Will this make the problem easier ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer

The characteristic function of $X$ satisfies a functional equation, namely
$$\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \phi_X(t/n^2) = \phi_S(t).$$
Solving this kind of equation is not simple.

If the distribution of $X$ is completely determined by its moments, or equivalently by its cumulants, then it is determined by the cumulants of $S$ since for every integer $d \ge 1$,
$$\kappa_d(S) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\kappa_d(X/n^2) = \zeta(2d)\kappa_d(X).$$

Comment: +1 for using cumulants! that indeed may provide a good answer to the OP

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan: Thank you.  Just want to confirm, in your answer, $\zeta(2d)$ is Riemann Zeta function at $2d$, am I right ?

Comment: @david Yes, since $\kappa_d(\lambda X) = \lambda^d \kappa_d(X)$.